# data pointer to std::vector

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am getting an exception with the following code snippet:

```
//      matlab mex program ...
float *ptr=new float[n*m];
.
.
.
std::vector<float> v(n*m);
v.assign(ptr);
```

How do I correctly assign `ptr` to the vector `v`?

Comment: *ptr=new *float[n*m] -> *ptr=new float[n*m];

Answer (score 2):

You can use either the constructor or assign, as you tried. However, you need to pass the length in some way. In the standard library, it's a common idiom to do this by passing the begin and end of a sequence - but those can be bare pointers. Like this:

```
std::vector<float> v; // Note you do not need the size here
v.assign(ptr, ptr+n*m);
```

or just:

```
std::vector<float> v(ptr, ptr+n*m);
```

It also seems like you have an error in your allocation:

```
float *ptr=new float[n*m]; // Allocate floats, not pointers to floats
```

Comment: How copy the pointer in pointer of std::vector<float> ?? avoiding too many data copy in the vector<float>.

Comment: You cannot, as that would violate encapsulation. However, you can get the a pointer to the data in the vector and only use that instead of using new to allocate memory: float* ptr = v.data();